# In Doctor who how many times did he regen

Tags: doctor-who, the-day-of-the-doctor

Well I say 15 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 - the tenth used the regen to fix himself then put all the energy in to his hand  11 - river gave him the power to fix himself and it went out of his hands 12 war doctor

So did he regen 15 times

Answer (score 9):

First, of all, by your math it should be 14. He didn't regenerate into 1, presumably he was born into the form that would eventually grow up to be William Hartnell.

Second of all, according to the list established in *The Time of the Doctor*, the River-related things don't count.

> The official list of regenerations that count is: 1 → 2 → 3 → 4 → 5 → 6 → 7 → 8 → War → 9 → 10 → 10.5 → 11 → 12. Each arrow is a regeneration. He's regenerated 13 times.